# Dropping time from datetime <[M8] in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

So I have a 'Date' column in my data frame where the dates have the format like this

```
0    1998-08-26 04:00:00
```

If I only want the Year month and day how do I drop the trivial hour?

Comment: obvious/obligatory what have you tried?

Comment: Just do `df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())`

Comment: I tried converting everything to a string and iterating but in the end since I need the df as a csv I just used the `.to_csv(file, date_format = '%Y%m%d'`. I also ended up using @EdChum solution which also worked thanks!

Comment: As a note: @EdChum's method is (for my case) about a factor 40 slower than the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The quickest way is to use DatetimeIndex's normalize (you first need to make the column a DatetimeIndex):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame({"t": pd.date_range('2014-01-01', periods=5, freq='H')})

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
                    t
0 2014-01-01 00:00:00
1 2014-01-01 01:00:00
2 2014-01-01 02:00:00
3 2014-01-01 03:00:00
4 2014-01-01 04:00:00

In [13]: pd.DatetimeIndex(df.t).normalize()
Out[13]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-01-01, ..., 2014-01-01]
Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [14]: df['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.t).normalize()

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
                    t       date
0 2014-01-01 00:00:00 2014-01-01
1 2014-01-01 01:00:00 2014-01-01
2 2014-01-01 02:00:00 2014-01-01
3 2014-01-01 03:00:00 2014-01-01
4 2014-01-01 04:00:00 2014-01-01
```

*DatetimeIndex also has some other useful attributes, e.g. .year, .month, .day.*

---

From 0.15 they'll be a dt attribute, so you can access this (and other methods) with:

```
df.t.dt.normalize()
# equivalent to
pd.DatetimeIndex(df.t).normalize()
```

Comment: Hi, can you show how to drop date from datetime? Using `datetime_column.dt.time` will leave the column as object not datetime anymore.

Comment: @rojas what do you want it to be? a timedelta?

Comment: Hmm, good question. I want to be able to merge two data frames on that time column (and don't want it to be a str object and have different format).

Comment: For a timedelta the one way is to subtract: `df["date"] - df["date"].normalize()`

Comment: Your mention of df.t.dt.___ saved me a lot of time. I read through the entire section on Time Series data and it was never mentioned. I am not sure where I was expected to look.

Comment: @CarlMorris I guess it's [in "basics"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor), but it should also be in Time Series really (it's very useful!)

Comment: @AndyHayden, thanks for pointing out where it is mentioned. I guess missing it is the result of my reading the docs through cherry picking and Google searches.

Answer (score 12):

Another option

```
df['my_date_column'].dt.date
```

Would give

```
0        2019-06-15
1        2019-06-15
2        2019-06-15
3        2019-06-15
4        2019-06-15
```

Comment: I feel like I just end up back at your answer every couple of weeks lol.  Wish I could give you more than one up vote.

Answer (score 1):

Another Possibility is using str.split

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.split(' ',expand=True)[0]
```

This should split the 'Date' column into two columns marked 0 and 1. Using the whitespace in between the date and time as the split indicator.

Column 0 of the returned dataframe then includes the date, and column 1 includes the time.
Then it sets the 'Date' column of your original dataframe to column [0] which should be just the date.

Answer (score -1):

## At `read_csv` with `date_parser`

```py
to_date = lambda times : [t[0:10] for t in times]

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', 
                  parse_dates={date: ['time']},
                  date_parser=to_date,
                  index_col='date')
```