# Panda's Joining two series by Day

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Typically we can simply run `df1.join(df2)` if the dates are perfectly aligned. However in my data set I have a slight mismatch with the index.

In `df1` the `pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex` format is `2004-07-07 20:00:00, 2004-07-08 20:00:00...` and in `df2` the `pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex` format is `2004-07-07, 2004-07-08,...`

I want to ignore the hours minutes and seconds and join these two `data frames`. No error is thrown but NaN values will appear for columns from `df2` on `2004-07-08 20:00:00`.  How can I join these two data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to reformat the datetime columns of one or both of your dataframes. Perhaps you could remove the time from your first dataframe, assuming the time is not important to you. [Here's a post which uses `normalize` to achieve this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786209/dropping-time-from-datetime-m8-in-pandas)

Comment: Awesome didn't know about `normalize`. the solution is simple, `df.index = df.index.normalize()`